# What is the meaning of "a buzzy sensation" in the paragraph below?

Tags: idioms, expressions

> He told himself he could do this. He felt a shiver of excitement, then **a
>   buzzy sensation**. If he made it through the night without sleeping,
>   he'd be a different person, somehow. A more important person.

The above paragraph comes from the book ***The Year of Billy Miller*** on page 134. As for the second sentence—*he felt a shiver of excitement, then a buzzy sensation*—what is the meaning of **a buzzy sensation**? Is it a feeling of excitement?

What is the difference between **felt a shiver of excitement** and **a buzzy sensation**?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the context, **a buzzy sensation** here is referring to *a strong feeling of anticipation*, a sensation that's powerful enough to resonate through the entire body.

In other words, the character is experiencing an intense sense of anxiousness in response to what the future (potentially) holds for him.

The **buzzy sensation** is that electric feeling of expectation often felt when one's life is about to transform and they find themselves perched on the precipice of profound possibility.

Comment: Reference? Also, is it used in both British and American English?

Comment: @freeling10  So the buzzy sensation here is quite same as the shiver of excitement, but the feeling of excitement is much stronger, right?

Comment: I would say so. The way I interpret it, the shiver of excitement is kind of what incites the buzzy sensation. He shivers, imagining whatever it is he's got in mind —then the buzzy sensation takes over as he relishes the potentiality of upcoming event(s).

Comment: In addition to what @freeling10 pointed out, I'd say that it can also equate to the expression/sensation of [**butterflies in the stomach**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterflies_in_the_stomach) which is defined as "the physical sensation in humans of a "fluttery" feeling in the stomach"